# How to get rid of output "java.lang.Exception

Tags: java, exception, throw

I have some simple code that I wrote but I don't understand why the output is the way it is.

Here's the code:

```
public static void main( String args[] )
{
    // ADD LOOP CODE, ADD TRY CATCH BLOCK(S) AS NEEDED BELOW
    // BE SURE TO LEAVE THESE 3 LINES IN THERE SOMEWHERE  
    // SINCE THEY CONTAIN THE EXACT EXPECTED OUTPUT TEXT

    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a = 0;
    String token;
    do
    {
        try
        {
            System.out.print("Enter int in range 1..100 inclusive: ");
            token = kbd.next();
            a = Integer.parseInt(token);
            if(a < 1 || a > 100) throw new Exception("Number:" + a + " out of range. Must be in 1..100");
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException nfe)
        {
            System.out.println("Input was not an integer");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
    while(a < 1 || a > 100);
    System.out.format("Thank you. You entered %d\n", a );

    kbd.close();

}
```

And here's the output:

Enter int in range 1..100 inclusive: -2

java.lang.Exception: Number:-2 out of range. Must be in 1..100

Enter int in range 1..100 inclusive: f

Input was not an integer

Enter int in range 1..100 inclusive: 3

Thank you. You entered 3

What I don't understand is why the general exception is throwing "java.lang.Exception: " before the desired output of "Number: a out of range. Must be in 1..100" Is there some way to get rid of this part of the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are throwing a java.lang.Exception so that is what is caught and that output is just the format of the exception's stdout. If you simply wish to print your string, just do

```
System.out.println("Number:" + a + " out of range. Must be in 1..100");
```

in the if statement block, because your while loop already catches the same condition, so the exception is redundant. i.e. you already check if the number is outside the range

Comment: This is not correct because other exceptions will result in a message about the input being out of range, which is misleading.

Comment: All other exceptions are thrown during the parseInt() line of code, so the if statement won't be reached. The print will only be output when parseInt() returned a valid integer. I edited my answer to clarify my print statement is to be added in the if statement block

Comment: This is incorrect also. The try block also includes ```kbd.next()``` so it is possible that some other Exception would be thrown, for example an IOException of some kind.

Comment: That is also before the if statement. I am confused how the print statement in my solution printed if the number is successfully inputted will be printed with these other exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

`if(a < 1 || a > 100) throw new Exception("Number:" + a + " out of range. Must be in 1..100");`

to this:

`if(a < 1 || a > 100) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input was not in range [1,100]");`

Then catch the exception and print only the message:

```
catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
  System.out.println("Input was not an integer");
}
catch(IllegalArgumentException iae) {
  System.out.println(iae.getMessage());
}
catch(Exception e) {
  System.out.println(e);
}
```

If you want some other text to display, then define the message as your argument when you create the new IllegalArgumentException. If you don't want the exception to cause any exception to be printed, then remove `System.out.println(iae.getMessage());` from your catch block.

This will allow you to define different behavior for 3 different cases:

- input is not an integer
- input is out of range
- all other exceptions